# Are healthcare service employees required to notify anybody (in general or particular) of a HIPAA violation?

Tags: united-states, medical, hipaa

I was notified by one of our patients that they received a "Summary of Today's Visit" in the mail, however, it wasn't their own "Summary of Today's Visit", it was that of another patient.

Knowing that this is a HIPAA violation, am I required to notify the patient whom's information was sent to the wrong person?

Comment: This is a question to ask your firm's lawyers, not the Internet.

Comment: @NateEldredge why not? Seems worthwhile to have that information publicly available

Answer (score 1):

[The requirements](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=0ed84c7423abdfca1fa81d772667435a&mc=true&node=sp45.1.164.d&rgn=div6) are imposed on ["the covered entity"](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=f175743556763460c01fca8b037a078f&mc=true&node=se45.2.160_1103&rgn=div8). You personally may not be required to do anything, apart from whatever your employer requires of you, but §164.404(a) says:

> A covered entity shall, following the discovery of a breach of
>   unsecured protected health information, notify each individual whose
>   unsecured protected health information has been, or is reasonably
>   believed by the covered entity to have been, accessed, acquired, used,
>   or disclosed as a result of such breach.

What you describe is a breach. That section provides other information about timing and content of notification.

Comment: I venture to suggest that not informing your employer that you know they are in breach of the law would be a breach of your employment contract notwithstanding that your employer may not have explicitly required this.